# Background task memory usage WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, memory-limit, background-task

According of this link [Microsoft Increases Memory Limit For Apps In Windows Phone 8.1](http://wmpoweruser.com/microsoft-increases-memory-limit-for-apps-in-windows-phone-8-1/) in my 2GB device available for background task **40MB** memory. But when I trigger my background task with breakpoints in a first string in Run method I see in *Windows Phone Developer Power Tools (8.1)* for my task Private Bytes is **30.73MB** Working Set **31.27MB**.
[MemoryManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.memorymanager.aspx) show me **35 Mb** in Run method.

1. Is it mean I can use only 40-30=10MB for my needs in background
   task?
2. Is it possible to change 30MB (switch off some requirements
   in manifest)?
3. How it work for 512MB devices where available only
   16MB memory for background task?

*P.S.* After reset of the phone and reinstall application I see only **2 MB** at the same string...
[image: Windows Phone Developer Power Tools (8.1)]
[image: MemoryManager]

Comment: "Private bytes" generally means the amount of ram that the application has asked for, not its limit.

Comment: How can I see current memory usage for my background task?